# More efficient way to write multiple UPDATE queries

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

Is there a better / more efficient / shorter way to write this SQL Query:

```
UPDATE mTable SET score = 0.2537 WHERE user = 'Xthane' AND groupId = 37;
UPDATE mTable SET score = 0.2349 WHERE user = 'Mike' AND groupId = 37;
UPDATE mTable SET score = 0.2761 WHERE user = 'Jack' AND groupId = 37;
UPDATE mTable SET score = 0.2655 WHERE user = 'Isotope' AND groupId = 37;
UPDATE mTable SET score = 0.3235 WHERE user = 'Caesar' AND groupId = 37;
```

Comment: Beware that some of the proposed solutions have the potential to update a LOT more more rows than the original, overwriting the existing score value with a NULL, where your original statements don't do that.

Comment: can the number of users change ? or the number of the group ? is this query going to be constructed dynamically ? or is the update constant and only the score changes ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
UPDATE mTable 
SET score = 
    case user
        when 'Xthane' then 0.2537
        when 'Mike' then 0.2349
        when 'Jack' then 0.2761
        when 'Isotope' then 0.2655
        when 'Caesar' then 0.3235
        else score
    end
where groupId = 37
```

Comment: I would add a where condition on user as well so you dont update 1,000,000 rows (most withthe same value they currently have) when only 5 need to be updated.

Comment: @HLGEM That depends on the data - it may be that there are only 5 users for groupId 37.

Comment: that is true - you do have to know your data, but I wanted the OP to realize he could potentially be updating many more records than intended.

Comment: This worked great.  It updated all rows with groupId = 37 but the ones that were not changed stayed the same.  There were about 16 rows so its not a problem.  Thank you :)

Comment: @HLGEM: and updating hundreds of thousands of rows that don't need to be updated is expensive in Oracle (in terms of concurrency, rollback and redo). And maybe he does want the `ON UPDATE FOR EACH ROW` trigger to fire for all of those "unchanged" rows as well. But why stop there, why not move the predicate on groupId into the case expression, and just update all of the rows in the table.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html) statement to perform this type of `UPDATE`.

```
UPDATE mTable
SET score 
   = CASE user
        WHEN 'Xthane' THEN 0.2537
        WHEN 'Mike' THEN 0.2349
        WHEN 'Jack' THEN 0.2761
        WHEN 'Isotope' THEN 0.2655
        WHEN 'Caesar' THEN 0.3235
        ELSE score
     END
WHERE groupId = 37
```

Comment: This will potentially update more rows than the original, and assign a NULL for a score to rows that have groupId = 37 and have user that doesn't match one listed in the CASE expression. There really needs to be an `ELSE score` in the CASE expression to guarantee we don't update those "unmatched" rows. Either that, or a predicate on the user column that limits the rows to be updated.

Comment: @spencer7593 you are correct, I updated it. I missed it when I was writing the query. thx

Answer (score 0):

You could create a temporary table, insert score, user and groupid for all the records you want to update then do something like this:

```
UPDATE
FROM mTable m
INNER JOIN tmpTable t
  ON m.groupId = t.groupId
  AND m.user = t.user
SET m.score = t.score;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original statements look short enough, and are easy enough to understand, and you can determine whether there were any rows affected on each of those separate UPDATE statements.

For a large number of statements, however, there's a considerable amount of overhead making "roundtrips" to the database to execute each individual statement. You can get much faster execution (shorter elapsed time) for a large set of updates by "batching" the updates together in a single statement execution.

So, it depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Better? Depends on how you define that. (Should the statements be more understandable, easier to debug, less resource intensive?

More efficient? In terms of reduced elapsed time, yes, there are other ways to accomplish these same updates, but the statements are not as easy to understand as yours.

Shorter? In terms of SQL statements with fewer characters, yes, there are ways to achieve that. (Some examples are shown in other answers, but note that the effects of the statements in some of those answers is significantly DIFFERENT than your statements.)

The actual performance of those alternatives is really going to depend on the number of rows, and available indexes.  (e.g. if you have hundreds of thousands of rows with groupId = 37, but are only updating 5 of those rows).